# How to capture the abscence of a library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have developed a custom library that I use in some projects.

Nowadays I'm implementing the `error capture` in my application. One of them considers the possibility that the machine where I try to execute my application doesn't have my libraries.

So what I made to check if the library was installed or not, was try to use it surrounded with a `try-catch` clause like this:

```
try
{
    MyLibrary library = new MyLibrary();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your library is not installed");
    Close();
}
```

This code should show a message when the library is not found, and then close my application. But the message is never shown.

Any idea on how to check if my library is not located in my machine?

Comment: maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343506/how-to-check-programatically-if-an-assembly-reference-exists-in-c)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current `try-catch` you can not catch that kind of exception because there are not related to your code. The Runtime will try to load the assembly, if it cannot be found, the `AssemblyResolve` event is raised.

```
class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolveEventHandler;

    }


    private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try resolving: " + args.Name);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great when I can help :)